# How to access Ansible variable that contains slash in his key?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have this info:

```
"ansible_lvm.pvs": {
    "/dev/sdb": {
      "free_g": "0.30",
      "size_g": "10.00",
      "vg": "docker"
    },
    "/dev/sdc1": {
      "free_g": "0",
      "size_g": "30.00",
      "vg": "vg_elasticsearch"
    }
}
```

I need to execute a task only is ansible_lvm.pvs."/dev/sdc1" doesn't exists, but I don't know how to access this variable as I cannot relay on his position in the array, and its name contains slashs.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like one with dot which is also present in your question:

```
vars[‘ansible_lvm.pvs’][‘/dev/sdb’]
```